# I can't get this to work as a JavaScript function (I get the return value I want when I console.log this but I can't call it as a function)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dictionary

I'm trying to get this to work as a function that I can call as a function on any string to get a returned value of `true` and `false` statements in an array form using `.map`-

I understand how `.map` works and can get it to return the values I want in a `new array` when I `console.log(lastArray)` but I cannot get it to work as a function that I can call on the string `lastArray(dirtyString)` or `finalArray("the cat pop racecar blue")` and get `[false, false, true, true, false]`. I can't use any loops and must use `.map` (but I've solved those problems as just `console.log-ing finalArray` returns a new array of correct values for me... I can just not see what I'm doing wrong & when I've tried re-working this, I get `Undefined`. I want to keep the methodology I have in place, I just don't know Why it's not working as a function I can call (& I've done hours of online research and have been working on this for days). Also, sorry my code is so messy & at times redundant & heavily commented (I've just tried it so many ways trying to get it to work, I'm kind of new to CS & JS). Also, when trying to call the function on a string, it also returns an error. Here's my code:

```
    /* split string into array of substrings, clean out extra spaces, return new array of substrings */ 

    var dirtyString = ("stash and pop on this level");


    var cleanArray = function(dirtyString){
      var splitString = dirtyString.split(" ");
      var cleanArray = splitString.filter(Boolean);
      return cleanArray;
    };

    var newArray = cleanArray(dirtyString);

    /* take each element of the array, if it's a palindrome, add a true element to new array using map; if it's not, add a false element to the new array... using map */

    ///helper function that returns correct value when I console.log it///
    var lastArray = newArray.map(function(x) {
      if (x === x.split("").reverse().join("")){
        return true;}
        else {
          return false;}
        });

  */attempting to put the logic in lastArray into a function I can call /*  

    var palindromicMap = function (dirtyString) {
      var cleanedArray = cleanArray(dirtyString);
      var output = cleanedArray.map(function(x){
        if (x === x.split("").reverse().join("")){
          return true;}
        else if (x !== x.split("").reverse().join("")){
          return false;}
      });
      return output;
    };
    console.log(lastArray);
*/returns correct outcome /*
    palidromicMap(cleanArray);
*/returns error /*
palindromicMap("cat pop racecar blue");
*/returns error/*
```

Comment: Is this really the bracing style you use for your `if/else` statements?

Comment: You can also do `return x === x.split("").reverse().join("")`

Comment: *** I meant lastArray() {not finalArray() } - sorry, too many array variables...

Comment: If you need to fix your question, you can use the "edit" link below the question to do so.

Comment: As far as I can tell the problem seems to be that the function palindromicMap expects a string but you give it a function. This function doesn't have the string `split` method and things go sideways

Comment: I just tried to have the x === x.split("").reverse().join("") as the return statement and still got undefined... {also, my cleanArray function was not a comment, just got stuck that way during cut & paste, I had so many comments & function drafts... and, I am just learning this so I know my syntax is a bit off,  it's actually been my biggest problem w/this as I am totally not used to this language & it's syntax at all...

Comment: I tried just plugging a string into the palindromicMap() function & also get an error as Undefined... I feel like I'm not using correct syntax here in the construction of this as a function...

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [this jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3vc5kaoa/). The function takes a string as a parameter but you gave it a function, resulting in a misleading error message.

Basically changing the invocation to

```
console.log(palindromicMap(dirtyString));
```

seems to resolve the problem.

Comment: omg, thank you so much-  I was just calling it wrong! I'm so new to JavaScript & seeing the the error msg was just driving me crazy... Thank You! omg, Thank You!